# Selenium Automation of button with image tag

Tags: java, selenium

Jsp Code:

```html
<button type="submit"
        class="btn btn-myButton10"
        id="bt1" name="saveapp"
        value="save"
        onclick="validationMsg1();checkValidations();">
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"> Approve</i>
</button>.
```

I tried automating this Approve Button by name,id,class,xpath and css selectors. Nothing seems to work. Ive also tried giving wait().

Is there any alternative way of automating a button in selenium  java on eclipse?

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-myButton10" id="bt1" name="saveapp" value="save" onclick="validationMsg1();                                               checkValidations();"><i class="fa fa-check-circle-o"> Approve</i></button>

Comment: what xpath you have tried?

Comment: Show us the code you tried

Comment: do you getting any error .. post the code you tried

Comment: @AnushaMD Your code trials for _...automating this Approve Button..._ please...

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Can you please clarify a little bit more what you are trying to achieve? Do you need to click the button automatically from one page?  Or do you need this button to do something when clicked ?